# Calculating computer utlization per day with multiple login sessions per day

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating a PowerBI daashboard to show the utilization of the computers\computer rooms at my organization. I am having trouble figuring out how to find the total minutes logged in per day for each computer and therefore what percentage of the day that computer was utilised for.

At the moment I only have the login length per login session, not per computer/login date combo. I tried to create a measure that was

```
Utilization % = 
SUM('Login Sessions'[BusinessHoursLoginLengthInMinutes)])/
SUM('Computer Labs'[Total Available Minutes for each computer 9AM-5PM])
```

Where the total available minutes for each computer is always 480 on each row in the table with the list of computers. I'm imagining this is where the issue lays?

The Utilization % I am receiving is 988% instead of something less than 100%

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: please post a snapshot of your data model and explain relations between tables.

Comment: Try understanding the math on dax calculations and check values to understand why the result. For example, create a variable for numerator, denominator and result. Then on the return change the variables to check what values are actually been used for the math. In that way you can explain strange results.
I agree with Rado, if you need more help, post more information